# Создать map<char[2], long long> на C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать map.

Comment: map<char[2], long long>.

Comment: Как вы хотите сравнивать ключи?

Comment: В смысле? Как обычные строки. По первой букве, если равны, то по второй.

Comment: Если вы хотите сравнивать только один символ, то почему не объявить map<char, long long>?

Comment: Два. Два символа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, можно объявить следующим образом

```
auto cmp = [](const char *a, const char *b) { return ::strcmp(a, b) < 0; };
std::map<char[2], long long, decltype(cmp)> m(cmp);
```

Однако, так как массивы не имеют оператора присваивания, то лучше объявить ключ, как имеющий тип `std::array<char, 2>`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    auto cmp = [](const std::array<char, 2> &a, const std::array<char,2> &b ) 
        { return ::strcmp(a.data(), b.data()) < 0; };
    std::map<std::array<char, 2>, long long, decltype(cmp)> m(cmp);
    m.insert({ { { "A" }, 'A' }, { { "B" }, 'B' }, { { "C" }, 'C' } });

    for (const auto &p : m)
    {
        std::cout << p.first.data() << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
A: 65
B: 66
C: 67
```

Если `map` содержит в качестве ключа строки, содержащие два символа помимо завершающего нуля, то нужно объявить ключ как `std::array<char, 3>`

Можно упростить код если в качестве ключа использовать не символьный массив, а тип `std::string`.

Тогда вы можете записать просто

```
std::map<std::string, long long> m;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Артур Не за что. Вывод из моего ответа - вам следует использовать map<std::string, long long>